# Firebase token to log to my api

Tags: api, firebase, go, firebase-authentication, jwt

I'm making a golang backend for a web app and an android app.
I use Firebase for authentication.
If I understand well,:

1. I should be able to authenticate in the web app
2. Get a jwt token from google
3. Use this jwt in `authorization: Bearer <jwt>` for making call to my api
4. Validate the jwt using firebase-admin-sdk

Can someone correct me if I'm wrong ?

I use this html test page to test my authent and log the token:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sample FirebaseUI App</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/2.5.1/firebaseui.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/2.5.1/firebaseui.css" />

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.9.1/firebase.js"></script>
    <script>
        var config = {
            apiKey: "foo",
            authDomain: "bar.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "fizz.firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "buzz-193910",
            storageBucket: "john.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "doe"
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);

        // Initialize the FirebaseUI Widget using Firebase.
        var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());

        var uiConfig = {
            callbacks: {
                signInSuccess: function(currentUser, credential, redirectUrl) {
                    // User successfully signed in.
                    // Return type determines whether we continue the redirect automatically
                    // or whether we leave that to developer to handle.
                    console.log(credential)
                    return true;
                },
                uiShown: function() {
                    // The widget is rendered.
                    // Hide the loader.
                    document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
                }
            },
            // Will use popup for IDP Providers sign-in flow instead of the default, redirect.
            signInFlow: 'popup',
            signInSuccessUrl: '/test-auth-on-success',
            signInOptions: [
                // Leave the lines as is for the providers you want to offer your users.
                firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
                firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
                firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
                firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
                firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
                firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
            ],
            // Terms of service url.
            tosUrl: '<your-tos-url>'
        };

        ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to My Awesome App</h1>
<div id="firebaseui-auth-container"></div>
<div id="loader">Loading...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the go middleware I use to validate the token:

```golang
func (f *Authenticator) Firebase(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        authorizationHeader := req.Header.Get("authorization")

        if authorizationHeader == "" {
            HttpError(w, NewError("invalid authorization token"), http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }

        bearerToken := strings.Split(authorizationHeader, " ")
        if len(bearerToken) != 2 {
            HttpError(w, NewError("invalid authorization token"), http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }
        token, err := f.FirebaseClient.VerifyIDToken(bearerToken[1])
        if err != nil {
            HttpError(w, NewError(fmt.Sprintf("invalid authorization token: %s", err.Error())), http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }

        [some custom stuff here]

        req = req.WithContext(context.WithValue(context.Background(), "decoded", firebaseUser.CustomClaims))

        next.ServeHTTP(w, req)
    })
}
```

However, when I call my API with the jwt I ctrl-c/ctrl-v from the web log, I get the following error: `failed to verify token signature`
I don't understand why. Any ideas ?

[EDIT] I moved forward, but still not reached the end. I think some people may find this topic useful so I continue to inform community of my progress.

After a while, I found another snippet to log the api key, I changed the `signInSuccess` callback to:

```
signInSuccess: function(currentUser, credential, redirectUrl) {
    firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true).then(function(idToken) {
        console.log(idToken)
        // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
        // ...
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    });

},
```

Which log the right token. I'm not a front end guy, I don't understand why I can get several distincts jwt, but here it is, it works. Now I get the following error: `ID token issued at future timestamp: 1518108929`

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I succeed.

### Error 1: Failed to verify token signature

So, to recap: my html test page didn't log the right token. The good code is the following:

```
signInSuccess: function(currentUser, credential, redirectUrl) {
    firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true).then(function(idToken) {
        console.log(idToken)
        // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
        // ...
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    });

},
```

### Error 2: ID token issued at future timestamp

My computer clock was not well synchronized with the mondial time. This is stupid.

Comment: I got the same error like your error 2. But i did not get your fix about that. Can you please check this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54891883/firebase-id-token-issued-at-future-timestamp-error-in-firebaseadmin-asp-net-sdk