# Firebase ID token issued at future timestamp Error in FirebaseAdmin ASP.NET SDK

Tags: firebase, ionic3, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am working on an Ionic 3 application where i have used google firebase for login. So, i needed to verify the firebase token in my back-end. I have used [FirebaseAdmin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FirebaseAdmin/)(**Version 1.2.0**) plugin for verifying the token.

```
    try
    {
        var firebaseAppInstance = FirebaseApp.GetInstance(firebaseAppName);

        if (firebaseAppInstance == null)
        {
            firebaseAppInstance = FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
            {
                Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("firebase-servicekey.json")
            }, firebaseAppName);
        }

        var decodedToken = await FirebaseAuth.GetAuth(firebaseAppInstance).VerifyIdTokenAsync(firebaseToken);

        if (userId == decodedToken.Uid)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
```

But, sometimes i am getting **Firebase ID token issued at future timestamp** error. And sometimes, i could verify the same firebase token without this error.

Can anyone point me out what's the problem here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be because `FirebaseAdmin` currently doesn't tolerate any clock skew. Consider filing an issue on GitHub.

Comment: I have already posted an issue here https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-dotnet/issues/28

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka, is there any way to bypass it?

Comment: Not at the moment. Assuming this is a problem with clock skew the SDK needs to implement a fix similar to https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-go/pull/211

Comment: Already one pull request is being made here https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-dotnet/pull/29

Comment: Yes, I put that together yesterday. Needs to go through our code review process.

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka, has it been released yet?

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka Any news? Has it been resolved?

Comment: Yes. It has been solved. Just update your package

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been resolved [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-dotnet/pull/29). Just need to update the new release of that package. Here is the [release notes](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-dotnet/releases)